# How to access the <body> tags using watir

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to compose an email through watir. So when I trying to access it, it has the <body> tag.  Can anyone suggest how to access it?

My system configurations

```
IE-8Inter code here
Windows-7
```

I did the following

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
@ie.text_field(:id,':13r').set 'sample'



HTML CODE






<iframe tabIndex="1" class="Am Al editable" id=":13s" src="" frameBorder="0"
              style="padding-bottom: 0px; background-color: white; padding-left: 
           0px; padding-right: 0px; height: 248px; overflow: visible; padding-top:  
      0px;" allowTransparency="" closure_lm_162187="null" target="[object]" 
    originalTarget="undefined">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>CSSSTYLEsheet</style>
    </head> 
             <body class="editable LW-avf" id=":158" role="textbox" 
            contentEditable="true" hideFocus="hidefocus" closure_lm_478727="[object Object]" g_editable="true"/>
</html>
```

I am trying to access it as textbox as the "role" attribute has the value as "textbox".

I got the error
:274:in `assert_not_readonly'
        from C:/svn/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.6.7/lib/watir/input_elem
ents.rb:368:in`set'

[image: I am Trying to compose the mail through Watir,the element that I tried access is body can anyone tell me how to access it]

Comment: Please post the HTML code instead of images.  It makes it easier to reproduce issues that way...

Comment: <body class="editable LW-avf" id=":158" role="textbox" contentEditable="true" hideFocus="hidefocus" closure_lm_478727="[object Object]" g_editable="true"/> Here is the Html code

Comment: Edit your question and put the html there as code so it is formatted and readable

Comment: @ Chuck van der Linden Hey i edited the question and added the code can  u look into it.

Comment: what version of the watir gems are you using?   from command line type `gem list`  and include the results for any gem with watir in the name.   Your primary problem is that the thing you want is inside a frame (maybe even nested frames, hard to tell without being able to access the site directly)  but the exact syntax for addressing frames depends on the version of watir being used, and if it is watir-classic or watir-webdriver.  You included both tags in your question so it is hard for us to know unless you tell us those details

Comment: watir(5.0.0,1.6.7) both versions are installed

Comment: Show us the code (and some lines before and after) where @ie is assigned. This is important to identify if you using watir-classic or watir-webdriver as driver for browser control. They have slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above it has iframe element try as

@ie.iframe(:id,':13r').body(:id,':13r').set 'sample'

Comment: Hey I got the below error when trying to execute with the above command @ie.iframe(:id,':13r').body(:id,':13r').set 'sample'
NoMethodError: undefined method `iframe' for #<Watir::IE:0x4ee6c28>

Comment: In watir-classic, there's no `iframe` method.  Instead, the method is [frame](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-classic/Watir/Container#frame-instance_method).

Comment: he is requiring watir not watir-clasic

Comment: He is requiring watir yes, but that is a wrapper around watir-classic and watir-webdriver, so without seeing how he creates the new browser object, hard to know for sure which is in effect.  But the error would tend to point to using classic

Comment: @orde, Watir-Classic does have the `iframe` and `iframes` methods. As seen in the documentation, they are an alias of the `frame` and `frames` methods. It differs from Watir-Webdriver, but the method does exist. Though given that the error message says `Watir::IE`, it is possible that an older version of Watir-Classic is being used.

Comment: @justin Ko can u please tell me how to access it,actually I am to access the body element which is under frame..................

Comment: @khan, are you the same person as shaik? I am confused by your question.

Comment: Not at all he is not same,actually we both are different people(college  colleagues) working on the same topic looks like he is also stuck at the same point

Comment: @Justin Ko.  Thanks for the clarification.  I'm getting rusty on watir-classic...

Answer (score 1):

There's a [`body`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-classic/Watir/Container#body-instance_method) method in watir-classic, and there's a [`body`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Container#body-instance_method) method in watir-webdriver.

Per the watir-classic documentation, you can locate the element a number of ways, including the id attribute or an arbitrary HTML attribute:

```
browser.body(:id => "htmlid")
browser.body(:foo => "value-of-foo-attribute)
```