# Access <body> HTML element using watir

Tags: html, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, watir-classic

Hi I want to compose the mail,the textarea of the mail has the following HTML code

Can anyone help me out how to access it using watir In have done the following steps but couldn't get it

```
irb
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'

@ie.body(:id,':158').set 'text'
```

MY system configuration is

```
IE-8
Windows-7

    <div class="Ar Au" id=":88" style="display: block;">
    <iframe tabIndex="1" class="Am Al editable" id=":83" src="html/compose/static_files/blank_quirks.html" frameBorder="0" style="padding-bottom: 0px; background-color: white; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; height: 245px; overflow: visible; padding-top: 0px;" allowTransparency="allowtransparency" closure_lm_423419="null">
<body class="editable LW-avf" id=":158" role="textbox" contentEditable="true"
    hideFocus="hidefocus" closure_lm_478727="[object Object]" g_editable="true"/>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/28796347/409820

Comment: Are you still using Watir v1.6.7 or are you now using Watir-Webdriver (as indicated by the tags)?

Comment: Yaa i am using watir 1.6.7 ,where as I am requiring watir-webdriver to run it on chrome but facing error on both browsers ............

Comment: Can you update the question with the error that you are getting?

Comment: Hey I added the code, I am trying to compose(writting content on the body) a mail on IE-8,it's actually pointing to <body> tag which is under <iframe>  which is further under <div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For editable elements that are not inputs, ie the body element in this case, there is no `set` method. For these types of elements, you need to use the `send_keys` method. Assuming a current version of Watir, the following will work:

```
@ie.iframe(:id => ':83').body(:id, ':158').send_keys('text')
```

As there should only be one body element in an iframe, you could also do:

```
@ie.iframe(:id => ':83').body.send_keys('text')
```

However, given that you are using Watir v1.6.7, several of these methods are different or do not exist. For example, there is no `iframe` or `body` method. As well, there is no `send_keys` method for elements. Instead you will need to bring focus to the body element and then `send_keys` to the browser.

```
@ie.frame(:id, ':83').element(:id, ':158').focus
@ie.send_keys('text')
```

Note that the element needs to be in focus, so do not take focus away from the browser when doing this.

Comment: When I used iframe I got the following error   NoMethodError: undefined method `iframe' for #<Watir::IE:0x503bc7c>
        from (irb):13
        from E:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:630
irb(main):014:0> @ie.frame(:id => ':160').element.send_keys('text')
ArgumentError: Argument id:160 not supported
        from E:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.6.7/lib/watir/frame.rb
:36:in `locate'
        from E:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.6.7/lib/watir/frame.rb

Comment: the other error which I got is NoMethodError: undefined method `body' for #<Watir::Frame:0x4f8c6f0>
        from (irb):27
        from E:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:630

Comment: I think you are using the wrong example. As I said in the answer, the first two lines of code are what you would do in the current version of Watir-Classic. Given that you are using the old version 1.6.7, you need to use the last example.

Comment: Please look at the syntax of the v1.6.7 example very carefully. The API back then had a number of differences, which makes the attempt `@ie.frame(:id => ':160').element.send_keys('text')` invalid. There are at least three problems with this attempt - (1) the `frame` locator needs to be passed in as two arguments not a hash; (2) the `element` method must take an argument; (3) `send_keys` method does not exist for elements. Please retry using the syntax shown in the example.

Comment: I tried with the example u have shown @ie.frame(:id, ':1zb').element(:text, 'Text - Empty Text Node').focus,here element is body and body has nothing in it rather these text 'Text - Empty Text Node' when I tried with it I got the below error,

Comment: These is the error, irb(main):008:0> @ie.frame(:id, ':1zb').element(:text, 'Text - Empty Text Node')
.focus
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: Unable to locate element, using :text,
 "Text - Empty Text Node"
        from E:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.6.7/lib/watir/element.
rb:58:in `assert_exists'
        from E:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.6.7/lib/watir/element.
rb:301:in `focus'
        from (irb):8
        from E:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:630

Comment: I tried with empty element and i got the below error irb(main):009:0> @ie.frame(:id, ':1zb').element().focus
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)
        from (irb):9:in `element'
        from (irb):9
        from E:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:630

Comment: when I tried without element I got the below error irb(main):010:0> @ie.frame(:id, ':1zb').focus
NoMethodError: undefined method `focus' for #<Watir::Frame:0x4e8beb8>
        from (irb):10
        from E:/Ruby_1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:630

Comment: Can you update the question with the complete and full HTML that you are working with? It is extremely difficult to help if you do not provide all the information.

Comment: hey can u tell me how to access these one <div tabindex="2" class="T-I J-J5-Ji Bq nS T-I-KE L3" id=":137" role="button" closure_lm_431673="[object Object]" unselectable="on">
<b unselectable = "on">
Text - Send

Comment: these is the send button in IE 8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72838/discussion-between-khan-and-justin-ko).